# How to maintain immersive mode when navigating to a new activity?

Tags: android, android-view

For example, I set immersive mode to an activity with

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

And then I have a button that starts up a new activity which I also want to be immersive. The target activity B also has code that enables immersive mode when in focus.

When a transition from activity A to activity B happens, there is a period of 0.5-1s when the app is not is not in immersive mode. I guess what happens is when a new activity is starting up, it's not known if it is going to be immersive or not, and only when `onSystemUiVisibilityChange` is reached, then it goes into immersive mode.

Is there a way to make sure that all transitions between activities stay in immersive mode? From where I am not it seems the only way is to use only 1 activity and then use fragments instead of new activities.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I ended up with having one `Activity` in immersive Mode and then changing `Fragments` inside it.

This is application that I am talking about: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.langmission